# Laravel check session timeout for fill form

Tags: php, laravel

in my login form i would like to set check session timeout for filling form, after fill form, i want to check long time, if session expired form must be recreate to fill by user, i'm using this method but i get error:

**My code:**

```
public function checkAccount(CheckAuthenticationRequest $request)
{

    if ((time() - Session::activity()) > (Config::get('session.lifetime') * 60))
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors('Login form no longer fill, you must be fill again')
            ->withInput();
    }

    ...
}
```

**Error:** for use above code

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Illuminate\Session\Store' does not have a method 'activity'

**Error:** if my form no longer fill by user and try to send form data

```
TokenMismatchException
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're importing the right class at the top?

Comment: Laravel's session store has no `activity` method, also you can't reliably determine when a session has expired because Laravel could of had already replaced the old session with a new one. So a practical way of handling this would be to add a session key, let's call it `is_active`, and then checking if that key exists `if (Session::has('is_active')) { ... }`. If the `is_active` key is still there it means the session has not expired, if the key is missing then it means the session expired and removed that key (and you'd need to put it back).

Comment: @JoelHinz yes sir. i wrote `use Session;` top of my class

Comment: @Bogdan unfortunately if my form no longer fill by user. i get `TokenMismatchException` error, and i must be handle it.

Comment: You can use Laravel's [Exception Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler) if you want to manually handle some exceptions at a global level. So you can this can apply this to `TokenMismatchException`, and if the exception is thrown then in `render` method of the handler class just `return redirect()->back()->withInput();` and you're done.

Comment: I think I found the page you got that code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688853/check-for-session-timeout-in-laravel - if you read the comments, it appears the `activity()` method was removed in Laravel 4.

Comment: @JoelHinz is right, `activity` is way back from Laravel 3 :). I've tagged that question properly so this doesn't happen to other people.

Comment: @Bogdan and how to check that in my custom function?

Comment: Just use this condition `if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) { return redirect()->back()->withInput(); }}`.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that Session doesn't have the method you are calling. Try with `Session::get('lastActivityTime')`

Implement `lastActivityTime` by setting the session like so: `Session::set('lastActivityTime', time())`

Comment: You might want to explain where that `lastActivityTime` session key is coming from, because Laravel has no such thing.

Comment: You should implement it on your own after each request: `Session::set('lastActivityTime', time())`

Comment: Then please include that in the answer so people know what you're referring to, instead of having to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.

```
class formController extends Controller{

    /**FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE FORM VIEW**/
    public function showForm(Request $request) {
        $request->session()->put("opendate", Carbon::now()); //put current timestamp in the session

        return view("myform");
    }

    /**FUNCTION THAT HANDLES THE FORM DATA**/
    public function public function checkAccount(Request $request){
        if(!$request->session()->has("opendate")) return abort(400);

        $open_date = $request->session()->pull("opendate");

        //check the difference between data in the session and now
        if($opendate->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()) > 10) //<-- expire minutes here) 
            return redirect()->back()
                            ->withErrors("Login form no longer fill, you must be fill again")
                            ->withInput();

        //success code here
    }

}
```