# Get Session Time Left in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, redis

I am using `laravel 5.6` and i use `redis` for my `SESSION DRIVER`:

**.env**:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

Now in my **web.php**:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session; 
Route::get('/',function(){
    if(Session::has('a')){
        return Session::all();
    }
    Session::put('a','test',10);
    return 'reload';
});
```

Now i want to **get my session time left with other url**.But i couldn't find any command to get it!

**Note** : i don't want something like `Config::get('session.lifetime')` or ... beacuse i set a custom time in third argument!! of `Session::put('a','test',10);`

**Example 1**:

```
Session::put('a','test',100);
```

After **30 min** i want to get time left(70)

**Example 2**:

```
Session::put('a','test',266);
```

after 40 min i want to get time left(226)

Comment: possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688853/check-for-session-timeout-in-laravel

Comment: No!!i want to set custome Time.in this answers they use defualt time!!and i want to know exact timr left

Comment: i dont want sesion life time! i want sesion time left for each session

Comment: @Omid But you said *"session time life"*...

Comment: 1.see the title.in title i said time left! 2.sorry for content!!! i update and add some example.